# Typeahead.js: clearing if no hint/before options are loaded

Tags: typeahead.js

See the screenshot below:

[image: selection_007]

the troublesome code is here at line 1095:

```
valIsPrefixOfHint = val !== hint && hint.indexOf(val) === 0;
isValid = val !== "" && valIsPrefixOfHint && !this.hasOverflow();
!isValid && this.clearHint();
```

It seems odd that we call clearHint() on what is already an empty string...

Ultimately the input is cleared. This only happens once and if i wait long enough for the network call to resolve this isn't an issue.

I'm loading in a list of options into Bloodhound and then triggering the appropriate re-init and re-renders but it appears typeahead.js is clearing the input when options haven't loaded yet. What is the prescribed solution when loading in what is essentially local/static data (as far as typeahead.js is concerned) and keeping any user input before the local data arrives? I don't see this situation when I have a remote url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up addingg a disabled: 'disabled' tag and adding a spinner.js next to the input.